# How does Haskell know to retain Nothing as nothing when passed to a lambda that returns Just x?

Tags: haskell

I'm just trying to understand why this doesn't error:

```
Prelude> Nothing >>= (\x -> Just $ x + 3)
Nothing
```

If I break the lambda down into individual steps:

```
Prelude> Nothing + 3

<interactive>:8:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (Maybe a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. Num (Maybe a) => Maybe a
```

and

```
Prelude> Just Nothing
Just Nothing
```

Comment: It doesn't really boil down to `Nothing + 3` because you aren't passing directly `Nothing` to the lambda (as in `(\x -> Just $ x + 3) Nothing`). You have to consider what `>>=` does with `Maybe`-values.

Comment: IOW, because `=<<` is not `$`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you write `Nothing >>= (\x -> Just $ x + 3)`, this is not at all the same as `Just $ Nothing + 3`. You're not actually passing `Nothing` as the value of `x`.

Instead, you're calling operator `>>=`, and you're passing into it two arguments: `Nothing` on the left and the lambda expression on the right.

Therefore, the result of this expression would be determined by the definition of operator `>>=`. Let's take a look at [how it is defined for `Maybe`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.18/base-4.12.0.0/src/GHC-Base.html#line-854):

```
(Just x) >>= f  =  f x
Nothing  >>= f  =  Nothing
```

As you can see, when passed `Nothing` as left argument, operator `>>=` simply returns `Nothing` right away, and doesn't even bother with the function that is passed as right argument.

Comment: Perhaps more clearly, the `Nothing` case can be written as `Nothing >>= _ = Nothing` to emphasize that the right-hand operand is ignored.

Comment: @chepner I have considered that, but decided that it may actually prove confusing, because now I also need to explain what an underscore means, and that it's not part of the magic.